# Azure Devops - Get release definitions by agent pool ID

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to find all the builds and releases that are configured to use a specific agent pool, using the .NET Client Libraries.

Assuming `agentPoolId`, I can get all the build definitions like this:

```
// _connection is of type VssConnection
using (var buildClient = _connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>())
{
    List<BuildDefinitionReference> allBuilds = await buildClient.GetDefinitionsAsync(projectName, top: 1000, queryOrder: DefinitionQueryOrder.DefinitionNameAscending);
    List<BuildDefinitionReference> builds = allBuilds.Where(x => HasAgentPoolId(x, agentPoolId)).ToList();
}

private bool HasAgentPoolId(BuildDefinitionReference buildDefinition, int agentPoolId)
{
    TaskAgentPoolReference pool = buildDefinition?.Queue?.Pool;

    if (pool == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return pool.Id.Equals(agentPoolId);
}
```

But I couldn't find a way to find the release definitions that have one or more environments configured to use a particular agent. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, many thanks to @amit-baranes for pointing me in the right direction.

I've changed his code sample to use the `await` keyword instead of using `.Result`, and use `.OfType<DeploymentInput>()` instead of `.Cast<DeploymentInput>()` (it was throwing some exceptions).

Oh, and the most important thing I've learned: **agent pool ID and queue ID are different things!!!** If you intend to use the agent pool ID to get the release definitions you'll need to get the correspondent agent queue.

Code sample:

```
// set agent pool Id and project name
int agentPoolId = 123456; 
string teamProjectName = ".....";

// _connection is of type VssConnection
using (var taskAgentClient = _connection.GetClient<TaskAgentHttpClient>())
using (var releaseClient = _connection.GetClient<ReleaseHttpClient2>())
{
    // please note: agent pool Id != queue Id
    // agent pool id is used to get the build definitions
    // queue Id is used to get the release definitions
    TaskAgentPool agentPool = await taskAgentClient.GetAgentPoolAsync(agentPoolId);
    List<TaskAgentQueue> queues = await taskAgentClient.GetAgentQueuesByNamesAsync(teamProjectName, queueNames: new[] { agentPool.Name });
    TaskAgentQueue queue = queues.FirstOrDefault();

    List<ReleaseDefinition> definitions = await releaseClient.GetReleaseDefinitionsAsync(teamProjectName, string.Empty, ReleaseDefinitionExpands.Environments);

    foreach (ReleaseDefinition definition in definitions)
    {
        var fullDefinition = await releaseClient.GetReleaseDefinitionAsync(teamProjectName, definition.Id);

        bool hasReleasesWithPool = fullDefinition.Environments.SelectMany(GetDeploymentInputs)
                                                              .Any(di => di.QueueId == queue.Id);

        if (hasReleasesWithPool)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{definition.Name}");
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<DeploymentInput> GetDeploymentInputs(ReleaseDefinitionEnvironment environment)
{
    return environment.DeployPhases.Select(dp => dp.GetDeploymentInput())
                                   .OfType<DeploymentInput>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was manged to get all releases by Agent Pool ID via Rest Api and not via NET Client Libraries.Hope that helps.

C# Code snippet:

```
public class ReleaseResponse
{
     [JsonProperty("value")]
     public List<ReleaseItem> Value { get; set; }
}

public class ReleaseItem
{
     [JsonProperty("name")]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("Id")]
     public int Id { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string tfsURL = "TFS URL";
     string releaseDefurl = $"{tfsURL}/_apis/release/definitions?$expand=artifacts&api-version=3.2-preview.3";
     const int agentPoolID = "AGENT Pool ID";
     List<string> relevantReleases = new List<string>(); 
     WebClient client = new WebClient();
     client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
     client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
     var releaseList = client.DownloadString(releaseDefurl);
     var allReleases = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReleaseResponse>(releaseList).Value;
     foreach (var release in allReleases)
     {
           string releaseInfoApi = $"{tfsURL}/_apis/Release/definitions/{release.Id}";
           var getReleseInfo = client.DownloadString(releaseInfoApi);
           var releaseInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TFSLogic.RootObject>(getReleseInfo);
           var deploymentAgents = releaseInfo.environments.ToList().Where(e => e.deployPhases.FirstOrDefault().deploymentInput.queueId == agentPoolID).Count();
           if (deploymentAgents > 0)
           {
               relevantReleases.Add(release.Name);
           }

     }

}
```

Find TFSLogic here : https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cb7aa0d9

Powershell Code snippet:

```
$tfsUrl = "TFS URL"
$releaseDefurl = $tfsUrl + '/_apis/release/definitions?$expand=artifacts&api-version=3.2-preview.3'
$agentPoolID = "Agent Pool ID"
$relevantReleases = @();
$allReleasesID = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($releaseDefurl) -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials).value.id

function getReleaseByAgentPoolID($releaseID,$agentPoolID)
{
    $ReleaseInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$tfsUrl/_apis/Release/definitions/$releaseID" -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials

    $deploymentAgents = $ReleaseInfo.environments | % {$_.deployPhases.deploymentInput.queueId} | where {$_ -eq $agentPoolID}

    if($deploymentAgents.Count -gt 0)
    {
        return $ReleaseInfo.name
    }
}


foreach ($releaseID in $allReleasesID)
{
    $relevantReleases += getReleaseByAgentPoolID -releaseID $releaseID -agentPoolID $agentPoolID   
}
```

**UPDATE :**

It took me some time,But i was able to achieve that with [azure-devops-dotnet-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples) 
I hope this example is finally what you are looking for.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.WebApi.Clients;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.WebApi.Contracts;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FindReleaseByAgentPoolID
{
    class Program
    {
        const int agentPoolID = 999;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var relevantReleases = new List<string>();
            VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new WindowsCredential(System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials));
            var tfsURL = new Uri("TFS URL");
            var teamProjectName = "PROJECT";

            using (var connection = new VssConnection(tfsURL, c))
            using (var rmClient = connection.GetClient<ReleaseHttpClient2>())
            {
                var releases = rmClient
                    .GetReleaseDefinitionsAsync(teamProjectName, string.Empty, ReleaseDefinitionExpands.Environments)
                    .Result.ToArray();

                foreach (var release in releases)
                {
                    var r = rmClient.GetReleaseDefinitionAsync(teamProjectName, release.Id);
                    var deploymentAgents = r.Result.Environments.SelectMany(e =>
                     e.DeployPhases.Select(dp =>
                     dp.GetDeploymentInput()).Cast<DeploymentInput>()).Where(di =>
                     di.QueueId == agentPoolID).Count();

                    if (deploymentAgents > 0)
                    {
                        relevantReleases.Add(release.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @amit-baranes but I'm actually trying to avoid the REST API, I'd rather use the .NET client libraries so I don't have to handle the serialization/deserialization. BTW I want to get the release definitions, not the releases.

Comment: Many thanks for your help @amit-baranes. I've done some changes to your code sample, see below.

Comment: I'm glad i could help you solve your question.
Nice to learn new things every single day !